# Perl, Unix Email: download csv in browser issue

Tags: perl, hyperlink

I have this:

```
    open(MAIL,"|/usr/sbin/sendmail -t");
       ## Mail Header
       print MAIL "To: $GLOB_OPT{email}\n";
       print MAIL "From: $GLOB_OPT{from}\n";
       print MAIL "Subject: $GLOB_OPT{sub}\n";
       print MAIL qq|Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii\n|;
       print MAIL qq|Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n|;
       print MAIL qq|MIME-Version: 1.0\n\n|;
       print MAIL qq|<h3>Download File :</h3><br>|;
       print MAIL qq|<a href="$GLOB_OPT{html}" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Click Here</a>|;
    close(MAIL);
```

I want to send the hyperlink to user so they can download the csv file in the $GLOB_OPT{html} path.

When I open the link in my email, it opens the csv in the browser. I want instead the browser to download the file. What can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [content-disposition](http://www.jtricks.com/bits/content_disposition.html) in http headers on the webserver's side. This even works with [.htaccess](http://www.givegoodweb.com/post/30/forcing-a-download-with-apache-and-htaccess).

As far as I understand, the way you send the e-mail has little to do with the save/display choice in the browser.

Comment: Indeed. A link is a link, and nothing in it can say "Download this". Content-disposition is the way to go.

Comment: @David-Dorward: I think they missed something in the standard, like `<a href="http://..." whattodo="save">`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the system `sendmail` command. Instead use the [MIME::Lite](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/MIME-Lite-3.027/lib/MIME/Lite.pm#Send_an_HTML_document..._with_images_included!) module.

They have a [coding example](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/MIME-Lite-3.027/lib/MIME/Lite.pm#Send_an_HTML_document..._with_images_included!) that pretty much does exactly what you want to do.

This way, you're not depending upon an external command that may or may not work (depending upon the system and its configuration).

Answer (score 0):

You could output the CSV via a script which sends to the browser first  mime-header "application/octet-stream" instead of the default 
[MIME type](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types) sent by apache(or the used server). You can also configure the server to send the header it self by associating the .csv extension with "application/octet-stream" mime type.
see also [The apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype)

Comment: so basically, i can't give a direct link to the csv. I have to send to another script which outputs the csv and changes to something like text/csv ...

Comment: You can. see the second link.
So in your case it will be something like


  "AddType application/octet-stream .csv"


in a.htacces file in the directory where your CSV files are.